# Usage of () vs Unit when creating a function to call a parameterless constructor

Tags: scala

I came across a situation recently where I needed to create a function to call a parameterless constructor. The following code demonstrates

```
class NoNumber() {}
val create : Unit => NoNumber = Unit => new NoNumber()
val nn = create()
```

This code compiles and creates a new instance of NoNumber and assigns it to nn as expected. However, there are a couple of things I wasn't expecting.

my first attempt (which doesn't compile), was as follows

```
val create : Unit => NoNumber = () => new NoNumber()
```

Why is it that Unit works and () does not work in the above example? I was under the impression that () was the one and only instance of Unit and as such the () seems to make the most sense.

Secondly I see the following warning when compiling the code

> Warning:(3, 22) Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been
>   deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want. signature:
>   Function1.apply(v1: T1): R   given arguments:   after
>   adaptation: Function1((): Unit) lazy val nn = create()

What does this mean and how should the code be changed to remove the warning?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Unit => A` and `() => A` are not the same thing.

`Unit => A` is syntactic sugar for `Function1[Unit, A]`, a function with a single argument of `Unit` that returns `A`. You're confusing the type `Unit` with the value `()` that has type `Unit`. i.e., you cannot say:

```
scala> val a: () = ()
<console>:1: error: '=>' expected but '=' found.
       val a: () = ()
             ^
```

`() => A` is syntactic sugar for `Function0[A]`, a parameter-less function that returns `A`. They are similar, but not quite the same.

---

As for the warning with this:

```
val create : Unit => NoNumber = Unit => new NoNumber()
```

If you were to have `val nn = create`, then `nn` would actually be a function, `Unit => NoNumber`. When you have:

```
val nn = create()
```

You are *actually* are doing:

```
val nn = create.apply(())
```

Confusing, yes? Hence, the deprecation warning. The former is simply passing `()` to a `Function1[Unit, NoNumber]`, but it looks awfully like a `Function0`. What you probably want is:

```
val create : () => NoNumber = () => new NoNumber()
```

Comment: I could say that `Function1[Unit, A]` and `Function0[A]` are nearly isomorphic, but @TravisBrown or @som-snytt would tell me why that is unclear. It's just a technicality that you can have a function with an argument of `Unit`. It probably isn't any more useful than a parameter-less function, but they are ever-so-different.

Comment: Makes sense.

The only thing that seems slightly odd is the point that:
 "Unit => A is syntactic sugar for Function1[Unit, A], a function with a single argument of Unit that returns A"

the arguments in the square brackets are types, so the function is a function that maps something of type Unit - ie () - onto something of type A - ie new A, so () => new A.  I don't yet see where my thinking is incorrect here, however I do see the point about Function1 vs Function0, and what I was looking for was a Function0. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, in that case I guess a Function1[Unit, ...] is something that should just  be avoided as it makes little sense

Comment: I'd add that `Unit` in `Unit => new NoNumber()` is actually the name of a variable, not the type.